# How to combine multiple arrays into single array using Typescript. Also display the combined array in accordions

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display multiple arrays data in accordions by combining them into single array.

I have an object which contains different arrays like

Fruits: Array(4),

Trees:Array(3),

Vegetables:Array(2),…etc.

I want to push all these arrays into one array and display them in separate accordions.

**Before Combine Array**:

```
{

Fruits:  [{label:’Apple’, text:’Red Color’},{label:’Mango’, text:’Yellow Color’},{label:’Orange’, text:’Orange Color’},{label:’Grap’, text:’Black Color’}]

Trees: [{label:’Maple Tree’, text:’Orange Leafs’},{label:’Redbud Tree’, text:’Pink Leafs’},{label:’Pine’, text:Green Leafs’}]

Vegetables: [{label:’Tomato’, text:’Red Color’},{label:’PumpKin’, text:’Yellow Color’},{label:’Carrot’, text:’Orange Color’},{label:’Onion’, text:’Red Color’}]

}
```

I want to combine above arrays into one single array as below by using Typescript and display them in accordion.

```
[

{label:Fruits, values:[ {label:’Apple’, text:’Red Color’},{label:’Mango’, text:’Yellow Color’},
{label:’Orange’, text:’Orange Color’},{label:’Grap’, text:’Black Color’}]},

{label:Trees, values:[{label:’Maple Tree’, text:’Orange Leafs’},{label:’Redbud Tree’, text:’Pink Leafs’},{label:’Pine’, text:Green Leafs’}]},

{label:Vegetables, values:[{label:’Tomato’, text:’Red Color’},{label:’PumpKin’, text:’Yellow Color’},{label:’Carrot’, text:’Orange Color’},{label:’Onion’, text:’Red Color’}]}

]
```

After combining them. Dispaly them in accordions. Please check the link for Image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34OjN.png)

Comment: Please try to format your question, it is not readable

Comment: Done please check Now. I want to display multiple arrays data accordions. Before displaying in accordion need to combine or add them to one single array.

Comment: Did you try to combine it in any way ?

Comment: const stageInfoGroups: Array<any> = [];
Object.entries(data.stageInfo).forEach(entry => {      
       const values = entry[1] as unknown[];
       if (Array.isArray(values) && values.length > 0) {
        const firstValue = values[0] as { label: string; text: string };
        stageInfoGroups.push({
         label: entry[0],
         values: firstValue
        });
       }      
     });

Comment: @davidArchA I've updated the question json object accordingly and provided an answer based on assumption that formatted data is correct. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using object `entries` along with `map` you can iterate over the key and value pairs in your JSON object and transform data in order to fit your accordion.**

```js
// Your object before transforming
var obj = {
  Fruits: [{ label: "Apple", text: "Red Color" }, { label: "Mango", text: "Yellow Color" }, { label: "Orange", text: "Orange Color" }, { label: "Grap", text: "Black Color" }],
  Trees: [{ label: "Maple Tree", text: "Orange Leafs" }, { label: "Redbud Tree", text: "Pink Leafs" }, { label: "Pine", text: "Green Leafs" }],
  Vegetables: [{ label: "Tomato", text: "Red Color" }, { label: "PumpKin", text: "Yellow Color" }, { label: "Carrot", text: "Orange Color" }, { label: "Onion", text: "Red Color" }]
}

var accodianDisplay = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({ label: key, values: value }))

console.log(accodianDisplay)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({ label: key, values: value }))
```

Should do the trick. This takes your original object, and get each key:value pair, map them to an array of objects where each "label" is the key and each "values" is the value part of the pair.

The full example:

```
 const obj = {
  Fruits: [{ label: "Apple", text: "Red Color" }, { label: "Mango", text: "Yellow Color" }, { label: "Orange", text: "Orange Color" }, { label: "Grap", text: "Black Color" }],
  Trees: [{ label: "Maple Tree", text: "Orange Leafs" }, { label: "Redbud Tree", text: "Pink Leafs" }, { label: "Pine", text: "Green Leafs" }],
  Vegetables: [{ label: "Tomato", text: "Red Color" }, { label: "PumpKin", text: "Yellow Color" }, { label: "Carrot", text: "Orange Color" }, { label: "Onion", text: "Red Color" }]
}

const formattedArr = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({ label: key, values: value }))
```

Result being on my NodeJS console:

```
[
  {
    label: 'Fruits',
    values: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  { label: 'Trees', values: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  {
    label: 'Vegetables',
    values: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

The result of formattedArr[0].values being:

```
[
  { label: 'Apple', text: 'Red Color' },
  { label: 'Mango', text: 'Yellow Color' },
  { label: 'Orange', text: 'Orange Color' },
  { label: 'Grap', text: 'Black Color' }
]
```

Now you just have to map the array to your accordion, simple html and ts job